# How to append asp.net literal control in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to bind asp.net literal control so I done by c# code like below..

```
private void GetMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                int cntr = 0; //toggle counter for alternating color
                string username = lblUserName.Text;


                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand();
                command.CommandText = "Get_Messages";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomId", lblRoomId.Text);
                command.Connection = connection;
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
                command.Dispose();

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    int i = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1);

                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        string personName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Username"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Username"].ToString();
                        string gender = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Sex"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Sex"].ToString();
                        string message = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Text"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Text"].ToString();

                        if (cntr == 0)
                        {
                            if (username == personName)
                            {
                                sb.Append("<div style='padding: 10px;text-align:right'>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append("<div style='padding: 10px;'>");
                            }
                            cntr = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (username == personName)
                            {
                                sb.Append("<div style='background-color: #EFEFEF;padding: 10px;text-align:right'>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append("<div style='background-color: #EFEFEF;padding: 10px;'>");
                            }
                            cntr = 0;
                        }

                        lblUserNames.Text = "<span style='color: Blue;'><b line-height:22px>" + personName + "</b></span>";
                        lblUserNames.Visible = true;

                        if (gender.ToLower() == "m")
                        {
                            if (username == personName)
                            {
                                sb.Append(message + "</div>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append("<img src='Images/manIcon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle;' alt=''>  " + lblUserNames.Text + " " + message + "</div>");
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            if (username == personName)
                            {
                                sb.Append(message + "</div>");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append("<img src='Images/womanIcon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle' alt=''>  " + lblUserNames.Text + " " + message + "</div>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    litMessages.Text = sb.ToString();
                    lblUserNames.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblUserNames.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Exception Message: " + ex.Message.Replace("'", "").Replace("\"", "") + "');", true);
            }
        }
```

but trying to do same in javascript and json but its not binding where as I get data successfully. where I am getting mistake cant understand, so please any one can help me for bind it javascript side..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           window.setInterval(GetRoomMessages, 10000);

           function GetRoomMessages() {
               var cntr = 0;
               var html = [];
               var roomId = getCookie('roomId');
               function getCookie(name) {
                   var nameEQ = name + "=";
                   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                   for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                       var c = ca[i];
                       while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                       if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                   }
                   return null;
               }

               var username = getCookie('userName');
               function getCookie(name) {
                   var nameEQ = name + "=";
                   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                   for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                       var c = ca[i];
                       while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                       if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                   }
                   return null;
               }

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   url: "temp.aspx/BindShopClothInfo",
                   data: "{'roomId':'" + roomId + "'}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (response) {
                       var sb = "";

                       for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                           var personName = response.d[i].Username;
                           var gender = response.d[i].Sex;
                           var message = response.d[i].Text;

                           if (cntr == 0) {

                               if (username == personName) {

                                   sb += ("<div style='padding: 10px;text-align:right'>");
                               }
                               else {
                                   sb += ("<div style='padding: 10px;'>");
                               }
                               cntr = 1;
                           }
                           else {
                               if (username == personName) {
                                   sb += ("<div style='background-color: #EFEFEF;padding: 10px;text-align:right'>");
                               }
                               else {
                                   sb += ("<div style='background-color: #EFEFEF;padding: 10px;'>");
                               }
                               cntr = 0;
                           }

                           $("#lblUserNames").val("<span style='color: Blue;'><b line-height:22px>" + personName + "</b></span>");
                           $("#lblUserNames").prop("visibility", "block");

                           if (gender.toLowerCase() == "m") {
                               if (username == personName) {
                                   sb += (message + "</div>");
                               }
                               else {
                                   var UserNames = $("#lblUserNames").val();
                                   sb += ("<img src='Images/manIcon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle;' alt=''>  " + UserNames + " " + message + "</div>");
                               }
                           }

                           else {
                               if (username == personName) {
                                   sb += (message + "</div>");
                               }
                               else {
                                   var UserNames = $("#lblUserNames").val();
                                   sb += ("<img src='Images/womanIcon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle' alt=''>  " + UserNames + " " + message + "</div>");
                               }
                           }
                       }

                       $("#litMessages").append(sb);
                       alert($("#litMessages").val());
                       //$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_lblProductName").html(Shopp.d[0].ClothName);

                   },
                   error: function (result) {
                       $("#lblUserNames").prop("visibility", "none");
                       alert("Error");
                   }
               });
           }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of 'literal' control use 'label' control..both are same just show text.